# How to count items in a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am making a blog app using django...

This is my model.py

```
class categories(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Blog(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    Blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    Description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')
    Blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_image', null=True, blank=True)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Categories')
```

I was wondering How to count the total no of blog present under a particular category?

I want to track a specific count rate for all Categories...

Comment: The answer is in the fine manual: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count the number of `Blog`s per `Category`, we can make an annotation on the `Category`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_blogs=Count('Categories')
)
```

But (as specified later), using `categories` as related name is downright wrong, and should be renamed to `blogs` since this is the reverse relation, in that case the query is:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    num_blogs=Count('blogs')
)
```

The result is a `QuerySet` containing all the `Category` objects, and each `Category` object, will have an attribute `num_blogs` that contains the number of blogs related to this category.

The advantage of doing this by annotations is that you avoid the "*N+1* problem": here we still perform *one* query, and not *one* query for the categories, and *n* queries to obtain the blog count for that specific category. In MySQL the query will look like:

```
SELECT category.*, COUNT(blog.id)
FROM category
LEFT OUTER JOIN blog ON blog.category_id = category.id
GROUP BY category.id
```

> **Note**: typically attributes in Python start wit a lowercase (and use underscores between words), so `blog_title`, and `category` instead of `Blog_title` and `Category`

> **Note**: the `related_name` is the name you give the objects of the *reverse* relation, so the `related_name` of the `category = ForeignKey(..)` should be `'blogs'`, not `'categories'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for title in categories.objects.all():
    Blog.objects.filter(Category__Title=a.title).count()
```

This would do what you are looking for.

Comment: Right answer, though it should be `Category__Title`.

Comment: This will work for only one object...not all...Do you have any solution for all objects???

Comment: This will definately work...But only for one category in the category list...I want it for all the categories django will automatically specify their counts...

Comment: this will work for all the categories and not one, once try it and check

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"category_title":category.Title, "count":Blog.objects.filter(Category=category).count()} for category in categories.objects.all()]
```

This will give a list of dictionaries with the category title and its corresponding counts

Answer (score 0):

Django: 2.2, Python 3.7

```
from django.db.models import Count

Blog.objects.values_list('Category').annotate(Count('Category'))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do with Category model also.

```
Categories.objects.filter(Title="someName").Categories.all().count()
```

Comment: This will work for only one object...not all...Do you have any solution for all objects in categories???