# Is there any possible solution for getting more than one value inside function in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a blog application using Django and I am also very much new to django.

This is the models I created

```
class categories(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='GST')





class Blog(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    Blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    Description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')
    Blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_image', null=True, blank=True)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blogs')
```

I was wondering How to count the total no of blog present under a particular category?

I want to track a specific count rate for all Categories...

Done something like this in my model

```
    def categories_count(self):
    for a in categories.objects.all():
        categories_count = Blog.objects.filter(Category__Title=a.Title).count()
        return categories_count
```

But it is returning only one value...Can anyone suggest me with some suitable codes to resolve this...

Thank you

Comment: You can construct a list, add an attribute to the `Category` objects, but the best is to simply annotate your queryset. Furthermore using the `title` here is *risky*: if two categories have the same title, the categories will "add up", and furthermore the counting will perform a `JOIN` which makes the query less efficient.

Comment: Your question is already answered in prev post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419681/10090254

Comment: Can you provide me with suitable codes accrding to this query???@Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of tuples of category title and blog count with the following query:

```
categories.objects.annotate(blog_count=Count('Categories')).values_list('Title', 'blog_count')
```

Comment: It is showing me this error 'Cannot resolve keyword 'blog' into field. Choices are: Categories, Title, id'...

Comment: @NiladryKar: yes, that is because you did not took the advice  to fix the nomenclature as well as violating PEP-8 and based on other questions violating probably a dozen design principles :)

Comment: @NiladryKar Fixed. Didn't notice your `related_name` for `Blog.Category`. You should rename it to `blogs` as WillemVanOnsem has already pointed out in your last question.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I should have done it earlier...Sorry about that@Willem Van Onsem....

Comment: But in my template it is coming out like this '<Queryset[(GST,2),(Incometax,0)]'...The values are coming perfectly....Can you tell me why this is happening?@Willem Van Onsem and @blhsing

Comment: The code I posted returns a list-like object of tuples, so your template should iterate over it in a `<% for title, count in categories_count %>` loop instead (assuming you name the variable that stores the returning value of the query as `categories_count`). See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: Thank you very very much @blhsing...It was a lifesaver for me

Comment: @NiladryKar: because there is a difference between a `QuerySet`, and a list of objects. But even with a list of objects, you need to do proper processing (for example by *iterating* over the collection).

Comment: Yeah I got that@WillemVanOnsem...Can You plz help me in one more thingh...How can I access objects through foreign key...Suppose in my model I want to access the 'Date' of the blog through categories...Can I do that???